# Want to Transfer Forum to a Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, forum, backups

I am Using WordPress CMS and using bbpress Forum plugin, I created a forum on WP site: `www.example.com/test/`

but now, i am looking to Transfer it to `http://test.example.com` , But I am not able to find the way to Export existing Forums, Topics and Replies from WP forum.

Is there any way to take backup of just forum section from my WordPress site and then upload it on subdomain, where I will use BBPress, which will make it easier for me to manage forums,

So, How can I take Backup?

Comment: Please ask this in a more relevant forum first, ie [BBPress Forums](https://bbpress.org/forums/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding a specific piece of software and is not about webmastering as specified by the on topic information for ProWebmasters - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic